# How can I change the transition animation of all activities

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I have the following in my style but it doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

What am i doing wrong?

```
 <style name="Theme.AndroidDevelopers" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Translucent</item>
        ...
```

Comment: Could you show how you try to apply the style to your application/activity? Does the other items in your style have an effect, and the problem is just with windowAnimationStyle?

Comment: You could create a base activity class that does the overrideTransition logic and have all your activities extend it.